# StringFormat 'c' always shows as US currency?

Tags: wpf, binding

The 'c' currency string format produces text in en-US format despite my PC's locale being set to something other. Am I doing something wrong or is this the intended behaviour?

Phil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this in `Application.Startup`:

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(FrameworkElement),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

more info: 
http://serialseb.blogspot.com/2007/04/wpf-tips-1-have-all-your-dates-times.html

Comment: It's worth noting this does not respect user's customizations. Eg I use en-GB and have customized my date format to "yyyy-MM-dd" in control panel. But unfortunately, WPF will use the default settings for the specified culture.

Answer (score 3):

So according to [Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/442569/wpf-binding-uses-the-wrong-currentculture-by-default) this behaviour is by design. You may be used to `String.Format` using the culture settings of the PC your application is running on but binding in WPF isn't intended to work that way:

> Binding converters never use the CurrentCulture - this is by design, so that their behavior is predictable across all machines and regional settings.
>
> However, you can specify the culture a converter should use. There are two ways to do this:
>
> > 1. Set Binding.ConverterCulture. E.g. `<TextBox Text="{Binding Birthday, ConverterCulture=de-DE}"/>`
> > 2. Set the xml:lang (or equivalently, Language) property on the target element. E.g. `<TextBox xml:lang="de-DE" Text="{Binding Birthday}"/>`

Which seems like you'd need to know in advance all the different cultures your application is going to run under. Which seems, well, a bit crap for everyone who has users outside of America.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken it depends on the culture setting in the running thread.

> System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture

or

> System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture

Comment: I see. So does the main application thread always default to en-US?

Comment: Not entirely sure I suspect it has to do with Regional Settings Location or Keyboard Language

Comment: That seems unlikely because all of my regional and keyboard settings are set to UK.